# Modules in Vert.X 3

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am new to Vert.X , I am interested in knowing how the module system is different in Vert.X 3 than 2 , I couldn't find any useful documentation for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vert.x 3 does not provide a module system and instead should be considered as a library and you are responsible for handling classloading.

Vert.x 3 provides however a service deployment, that you can use to package vertx services https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-factory/java/ .